# Hide tabs on keyboard open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-tabs

I want to hide my tabs when the keyboard is open, and show the tabs again when the keyboard is closed.

I know that I can go just for "AdjustSpan", and thats it, but the problem is that if I do that, the keyboard also hides an input that I have for a chat, because its a footer.

Whats the best way to hide the tabs?

I already tried with [ngClass] in , I tried with Keyboard.disableScroll, and also in app.module.ts using the parameters scrollAssist and autoFocusAssist with false value...

Nothing seems to work.

Any idea of how should I hide the tabs??

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 10):

You have to add an eventlistener for keyboard-interaction to add (or remove) some css class to the body-tag. In ionic1 the class "hide-on-keyboard-open" was added by default from the framework. In ionic2 you have to walk the "custom-implementation-path". So, here is what you are looking for:

1) Install keyboard-plugin and node_modules as described in ionic2 docs:

```
ionic plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

2) Add the plugin to your app.modules.ts

3) Add the desired eventlister withiin the device-ready event in your app.component.ts:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();

        this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() => {
            document.body.classList.add('keyboard-is-open');
        });

        this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() => {
            document.body.classList.remove('keyboard-is-open');
        });
})
```

4) Add the class defintion to your app.scss with a additional class-attribute (hideElementOnKeyboardShown)

```
body.keyboard-is-open .hideElementOnKeyboardShown{
    display: none;        
}
```

5) Add the class to the desired element, eg an footer, div or sth else:

```
<ion-footer class="hideElementOnKeyboardShown">
    <button round ion-button (click)="onLogin()"  block>
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" padding></ion-icon>
            Login
    </button>
</ion-footer>
```

6) in this case, put the ion-footer tag within the content-tag, otherwise the calculated viewheight isnt correct when keyboard is shown.

have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

just add the following lines to your config.xml..

```
 <platform name="android">

<preference name="android- 
      manifest/application/activity/@android:windowSoftInputMode" 
   value="adjustPan" />

....
</platform>
```

What this does is modify the default value that Cordova writes to your AndroidManifest.xml to control the global keyboard input behaviour for your app.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve that by writing a directive that subscribes to the Keyboard events and then adds(hide)/removes(show) a css property/class (display: none) to the tabs element once the keyboard is shown/hidden.

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'ion-tabs[hideTabs]',
})
export class HideTabsDirective implements OnDestroy {
    private static CSS_CLASS_NAME = 'hide-tab-bar';

    private show: Subscription;
    private hide: Subscription;

    constructor(element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer, keyboard: Keyboard) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.show = keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() =>
                renderer.setElementClass(element.nativeElement, 'hide-tabs', true)
            );

            this.onKeyboardHideSubscription = keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() =>
                renderer.setElementClass(element.nativeElement, 'hide-tabs', false)
            );
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.hide !== undefined) {
            this.hide.unsubscribe();
        }
        if (this.show !== undefined) {
            this.show.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

add css class in app.scss (for example):

```
.hide-tabs {
display: none;
}
```

on your tabs element `<ion-tabs hideTabs> </ion-tabs>`

**code added for proof of concept