# Hide Footer When keyboard is opened ionic4

Tags: ionic4

referred to this link: 
[Hide footer on keyboard open Ionic3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386422/hide-footer-on-keyboard-open-ionic3)

But then also issue is the same

[image]

Issue is same as in above image.... I have just added button in footer...

**.html file**

```
<ion-content>
<textarea placeholder="Please leave your review"></textarea>
<ion-content>

<ion-footer>
<ion-button (click)="submit()">Submit</ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```

So, When click on textarea, keyboard opens and the buttons appears to be above the keyboard.

I want whenever the keyboard opens.....the footer get hide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## IONIC 4

**Step:1** You need to install native keyboard plugin for using keyboard methods. You can install it from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard).

**Step:2** Then import it in your page.ts file like this

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';
```

**Step:3** Then put it in the providers under @Component as

```
@Component({
providers: [Keyboard]
})
```

**Step:4** After that , make a constructor for keyboard in your class in constructor section. Repeat same step 2-4 in your app.component.ts file

```
constructor(public keyboard:Keyboard) {
  }
```

**Step:5** Then take a variable to default hide keyboard on load of the page as in your class:

```
isKeyboardHide=true;
```

**Step:6** After that, all you need to call default methods of keyboard in ionWillEnter method and on show put the variable value as false for showing keyboard.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.keyboard.onKeyboardWillShow().subscribe(()=>{
      this.isKeyboardHide=false;
      // console.log('SHOWK');
    });

    this.keyboard.onKeyboardWillHide().subscribe(()=>{
      this.isKeyboardHide=true;
      // console.log('HIDEK');
    });
  }
```

**Step:7** Hide and show bottom div or footer accordingly.

```
//// FOR DIV BOTTOM DIV////
    <div class="" *ngIf="isKeyboardHide">
    </div>
//// OR FOR FOOTER ////
    <ion-content></ion-content>

    <ion-footer *ngIf="isKeyboardHide">
    </ion-footer>
```

Comment: @annaya, did you get the solution?

Comment: Using Angular/Ionic6 with capacitor i've had to do the following on install:
1. npm install cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
2. npm install @ionic-native/keyboard
3. ionic cap sync

I prefer to provide Keyboard in the .module file instead of the component itself.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is use 'inVisible' property to hide footer or div.

for example:

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="!keyboard.isVisible">
 I am footer!
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: This still works ^ for Ionic 5 -- but you need the `import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';` and `providers: [Keyboard]` and `constructor(public keyboard:Keyboard)` as per @Diksha235's answer